# Mods should not delete questions without closing or commenting on it

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

The question [All versions of Ruby as online-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068088/all-versions-of-ruby-as-online-services) was deleted without being closed, and without any comments by the deleter. (Meta question about that specific question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182792/another-why-did-you-delete-my-question )

It was asked by [Nakilon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322020/nakilon), and answerers to that question include [Jorg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/jorg-w-mittag), who is no idiot.

In general, questions ought to be closed, or have a comment explaining a deletion, before being deleted.

I'm not asking for this to be a software-based requirement (if someone needs to delete a question about Salman Rushdie's address, they should be able to do so immediately, rather than having to put in a comment first), but more as a social convention.

Comment: It was a external resource request question; very much off-topic. A moderator nuked it, quite justifiable.

Comment: There, I fixed it.

Comment: While it would probably put way too much on a strain on already overworked moderators, I'm not completely opposed to this. Deletions of years-old questions are frequently "WTF?" moments

Comment: I think people are focusing too much on the example question here. He's not necessarily contesting that the question should be *open*, only that there should be some information *on the question* indicating why it has been deleted. I happen to agree with him.

Comment: Not sure this is possible on SO; too many questions, too little time. Agree for most other sites.

Comment: That was during my cleanup of the [tag:online-services] tag. A tag begging people to spam StackOverflow. I forget how many questions were in that tag.  Multiple hundreds, undoubtedly.